# Working of Robot class

Tags: java, awtrobot

I know that Robot class in java is used to generate`Inputevents` such as `mouseMove`,`press` and `release` and also `keyevents` ,i know only the functionality i.e if i call `mouseMove(x,y)` mousepointer will move to the `(x,y)` position.I don't know ,Actually what happens inside i.e what are the steps take by `JVM` to interact with os to move the mouse pointer and other events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about the Java library is that [a lot of it is opensource](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Robot.java). A quick glance through it shows that on Unix-ish platforms it creates a `XToolkit` and then there's a lot of interfacing with the X11 library to send keyboard and mouse events.

In particular, all of the events are eventually dispatched to [sun.awt.X11.XRobotPeer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/awt/X11/XRobotPeer.java#XRobotPeer.mouseMoveImpl%28sun.awt.X11GraphicsConfig%2Cint%2Cint%29), who then dispatches them to [awt_Robot.c](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/solaris/native/sun/awt/awt_Robot.c) who then calls various X11 functions to produce particular events.

Comment: I still want clear answer and not deep;i understand that x11 library is used to interact with os.

Comment: The X11 library is essentially as deep as it gets; X11 then routes the events to the appropriate programs. Added a few more code references to help you out; honestly the best way is to search through the code and read through the docs